# Incremental Counter Prefix in Text File

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to create a PowerShell script that will scan a folder and its subfolders for videos and create a playlist file.

**Playlist Format:**

> DAUMPLAYLIST
>   1*file*%filename%
>   2*file*%filename%
>   3*file*%filename%
>   4*file*%filename%
>   ..and so on

So far my script successfully formats everything correctly except for the first incremental number. I can't figure out how to program PowerShell to add a counter prefix before each object.

**My script's format.**

> DAUMPLAYLIST
>   *file*%filename%
>   *file*%filename%
>   *file*%filename%
>   *file*%filename%
>   ..and so on

My script:

```
$formats = @("*.avi","*.mp4","*.flv","*.mpg","*.wmv","*.mpeg","*.mov","*.h265","*.mkv","*.asf","*.WebM","*.m4a","*.lnk","*.h264")  
$dir = Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path  
Add-Content 01.dpl DAUMPLAYER  
gci D:\Video\01\ -Include $formats -Recurse |
  ForEach-Object -Process { "*file*" + $_ } |
  Add-Content .\01.dpl
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add a counter to your loop:

```
$i = 0
Get-ChildItem 'D:\Video\01' -Include $formats -Recurse |
  ForEach-Object { "{0}*file*{1}" -f $i, $_.Name; $i++ } |
  Add-Content .\01.dpl
```

Another option is to collect the file list in a variable and process that list with a `for` loop:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem 'D:\Video\01' -Include $formats -Recurse
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $files.Count; $i++) {
  "{0}*file*{1}" -f $i, $files[$i].Name | Add-Content .\01.dpl
}
```

The [format operator](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7855.using-the-f-format-operator-in-powershell.aspx) (`-f`) also allows you to define specific number formats, for instance leading zeroes (`{0:d3}`).